# SystemStackError (stack level too deep) in sunspot gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I know this is the hardest error to trace. This is what happens:
I am doing a request involving sunspot search. For all requests that return reasonable solr response size, everything works fine. For a specific request where solr response is more than 1 MB, I get this error:

```
SOLR Request (186.0ms)  [ path=#<RSolr::Client:0x00000006f76c18> parameters={data: fq=type%3AArticle&fq=review_im%3A46&start=0&rows=0&facet=true&f.source_i.facet.mincount=1&facet.field=source_i&facet.field=language_i&facet.field=publication_types_im&facet.field=features_im&facet.field=locations_im&facet.field=keyphrases_im&facet.field=journal_i&facet.field=authors_im&facet.field=year_i&f.language_i.facet.mincount=1&f.publication_types_im.facet.mincount=1&f.features_im.facet.mincount=1&f.locations_im.facet.limit=30&f.locations_im.facet.mincount=1&f.keyphrases_im.facet.limit=30&f.keyphrases_im.facet.mincount=1&f.journal_i.facet.sort=true&f.journal_i.facet.limit=-1&f.journal_i.facet.mincount=1&f.authors_im.facet.sort=true&f.authors_im.facet.limit=-1&f.authors_im.facet.mincount=1&f.year_i.facet.limit=-1&f.year_i.facet.mincount=1&q=%2A%3A%2A, method: post, params: {:wt=>:ruby}, query: wt=ruby, headers: {"Content-Type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}, path: select, uri: http://localhost:8982/solr/select?wt=ruby, open_timeout: , read_timeout: , retry_503: , retry_after_limit: } ]
Solr Select (186.3ms)  fq=type%3AArticle&fq=review_im%3A46&start=0&rows=0&facet=true&f.source_i.facet.mincount=1&facet.field=source_i&facet.field=language_i&facet.field=publication_types_im&facet.field=features_im&facet.field=locations_im&facet.field=keyphrases_im&facet.field=journal_i&facet.field=authors_im&facet.field=year_i&f.language_i.facet.mincount=1&f.publication_types_im.facet.mincount=1&f.features_im.facet.mincount=1&f.locations_im.facet.limit=30&f.locations_im.facet.mincount=1&f.keyphrases_im.facet.limit=30&f.keyphrases_im.facet.mincount=1&f.journal_i.facet.sort=true&f.journal_i.facet.limit=-1&f.journal_i.facet.mincount=1&f.authors_im.facet.sort=true&f.authors_im.facet.limit=-1&f.authors_im.facet.mincount=1&f.year_i.facet.limit=-1&f.year_i.facet.mincount=1&q=%2A%3A%2A
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 650ms

SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:70


  Rendered /home/hammady/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /home/hammady/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /home/hammady/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (8.7ms)
2013/04/08 08:53:05 [error] 7480#0: *6 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /reviews/46/results?mode=visible&polling=1&search=all HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/passenger_helper_server:", host: "localhost:4000"
```

Is this a sunspot bug?

Update: No, that's a ruby VM issue, I reported it [here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8253).

Comment: Filed a [sunspot bug](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/issues/395)

Comment: Can you try to get a full stack trace, and a complete response from Solr?

Comment: The above stack trace is the maximum I could get from such exception. The complete Solr response can be found [here](http://da.qcri.org/solr-response-46-70000.txt).

Answer (score 0):

I notice you're using ruby-1.9.2-p320, and a similar issue was reported in another gem (delayed_job) where `reloader.rb` was causing a `SystemStackError`:

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/349

Several people (though not quite everyone) in that thread reported it fixed by upgrading to Ruby 1.9.3, so you may want to try that.

Comment: I am sorry this didn't solve the problem, the threshold is something around 640 KB solr responses. The problem is directly related to the response size (or the facet limit which causes the size variation)